# Update a dead person's situation in Italy - Who can do it?

Tags: civil-law, marriage, death, italy, birth-certificate

My great-grandfather was born in Italy and emmigrated from there when he was 16 years old. He married and died in Brazil, and his daughter (also born in Brazil) is my grandmother.

To obtain an Italian passport, I was informed by the consulate in my state of Brazil that the process could be faster if the situation of my great-grandfather in the prefecture was updated. That is, if someone could go there and deliver his marriage and death certificates (translated to Italian) and thus this would be annotated in his birth certificate.

I went there and delivered the documents. However, they phoned me 6 months later saying that they weren't sure that I was able to do this update (they checked my ID, however they did not ask for any proof that I am indeed his great-grandson). I was left wondering: Who can do that? Do I have the authorization to do it?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the Italian *Codice Civile* or on the Ministry of Foreign Affairs website that indicates you need specific permission, parentage, or authorization in order to hand over translated and legalized documents to be transcribed in a citizen's *Atto di Nascita*.

I would suggest you offer them an [*autocertificazione* ("self-certification")](https://www.esteri.it/mae/en/servizi/italiani-all-estero/autocertificazione_0.html) that you are the decedent's great-grandson and that he was married and died according to the documentation you delivered. These declarations are used frequently in Italian bureaucratic situations to save time, and there are lots of templates online that you can copy and adapt to your situation.

(The link above states explicitly that an *autocertificazione* may be used to certify the "*nascita del figlio, **decesso** del coniuge, **dell'ascendente** o discendente*.")